# Debugging ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, java-10

After a Java 10 migration, I am encountering an error `java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError`

With no other info. Error occurs when I try to run/debug the project. Where should I begin looking to diagnose this?

Here is the full output in the console:

```
Information:java: Errors occurred while compiling module 'pw-support-server_main'
Information:javac 10.0.2 was used to compile java sources
Information:11/27/2018 6:06 PM - Compilation completed with 1 error and 0 warnings in 2 s 173 ms
Error:java: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

Comment: Seems like you're either using an **incompatible version of IntelliJ** OR the error shared by you is incomplete still.

Comment: Seems issue is related to Lombok plugin: https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1572

Comment: You can try to set breakpoints in the constructors of `ExceptionInInitializerError`.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved using the following steps, which are probably very specific to my situation:

Changes to build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath "io.franzbecker:gradle-lombok:1.10"
    }
}
```

Changed to `classpath "io.franzbecker:gradle-lombok:1.14"` (update to latest version)

Added inside of  the block `allprojects {`

```
lombok {
    version = "1.18.4"
    sha256 = ""
}
```

The Franzbecker-lombok thing defaults to installing lombok 1.16.20, which has this issue. Telling gradle to use lombok's latest version solved this. Getting the right syntax among all the gradle version changes, Java version changes, etc, was just a little confusing.

Side note: The issue also occurred on Java 11.